# building assembly on sublime text with nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, sublimetext3

I have no knowledge on how to write assembly or compile it yet. I believe this code works for a "hello world" example;

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov edx, len    ;message length
    mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (sftdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
```

I want to build it using sublime text 3. I have this build file;

```
{
  "shell": true,
    "cmd": ["nasm -f macho ${file} && gcc -arch i386 -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.o"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
}
```

I get this error;

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

What is wrong with this setup?

Comment: The assembly code is fine. It will run only on a linux system, because int 0x80 is a linux system call. But I cannot help with the linker stuff as I use nasm + ld on linux instead. This is how my binary creating is done on linux: nasm -g -f elf32 ${binary_name}.asm and ld -m elf_i386 -static -o ${binary_name} ${binary_name}.o

Comment: `gcc` is an alias for `clang` on your machine, is that correct?

Comment: See if you can find a build log, there must be something more than `exit code 1`. And do you get the same error if you try to run the build command manually from a shell?

Comment: Your link is probably failing because you don't have a `main` symbol. Change `_start` to `_main` and you'll probably get it to go. As @Blechdose says, this program won't work on your Mac, even if you do get it to build successfully.

Comment: @Ruud, OP appears to be using a mac (the `-f macho` is the tipoff), so yes, `gcc` is just a copy of `clang` by default.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
"shell": true,
"cmd": ["nasm -f elf64 ${file} && ld -s -o ${file_base_name} ${file_base_name}.o"],
"file_regex": "^(.+):([0-9]+)()?: error: (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.assembly"
```